# Left Join is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I wrote following query

```
SELECT 
   us.Id as Id, us.Name as Name,
   SUM(CASE WHEN c.isPublish = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PendingCoupons,
   SUM(CASE WHEN c.isPublish = 1 and convert(date,c.PublishedDate,101) >=  convert(date, GETDATE(), 101) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ApprovedCouponsToday,
   SUM(CASE WHEN c.isPublish = 0 and convert(date,c. CreateDate, 101) = convert(date, GETDATE(), 101) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PendingCouponsToday,
   SUM(CASE WHEN c.isPublish = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ApprovedCoupons,
   SUM(CASE WHEN c.isPublish = 1 and c.Userid = us.Id and convert(date, c.PublishedDate, 101) >= convert(date, GETDATE(), 101) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ApprovedByUserToday,
   SUM(CASE WHEN c.isPublish = 1 and c.Userid = us.Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ApprovedByUser,
   SUM(CASE WHEN c.ReviewVerify = 1 and convert(date, c.PublishedDate, 101) >= convert(date, GETDATE(), 101) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ProcessToday,
   COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM 
   Users AS us
LEFT JOIN 
   Coupon c ON Userid = us.Id
GROUP BY 
   us.Name , us.Id
```

and I have following two tables

[image: Tables]

and after running above query the result is always this

[image: Result]

Is there any error in this query , because its always returning me count " 0 "  and I have almost 100 coupons on every user but its not showing

Comment: I set up an example and definitely didn't get your results; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/33ec0/1

Comment: You don't need the `and c.Userid = us.Id` inside the CASE expressions.

Comment: What datatypes are the `CreateDate` and `PublishDate` columns?

Comment: does 1 user have more than 1 coupon? or Does 1 coupon is for 1 user??

Comment: @ypercube there type is `datetime`

Comment: one coupon is for only one user and one user can have multiple coupons

Comment: Guys after working on @Barry Kaye's answer i got fine result but now thee problem is that i am getting result of one user where as i want to get result for all user whether he approved some coupons or not

Comment: Can you try this query: `SELECT us.Id, COUNT(c.Userid) AS Total
FROM Users AS us LEFT JOIN Coupon c ON c.Userid = us.Id GROUP BY us.Id ;` and shows the results?

Comment: @ypercube `Total` is 0 for all users

Comment: @smartboy Then no coupons have Userid set to any existing user...?

Comment: As @Joachim's comment, your users have no coupons :)

Comment: @ypercube you are right , now how could i consider Joachim's Comment as answer ?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Can you write your fiddler as answer ?

Comment: So, what values does `Coupon.Userid` have? Nulls or UserIDs that are not in `User.Id`?

Comment: They have Nulls , but now i fixed that , but how can i consider @JoachimIsaksson's comment as answer

Comment: @smartboy I think ypercube should get the cred here, my comment wasn't exactly an answer, just a way to debug (which his select did better :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson , i think you both are right but how to answer this question now ?

Comment: @smartboy Why are PublishDate and CreateDate not stored as DATE or DATETIME?

Comment: @smartboy Added a quick answer that tries to give an explanation of the problem and how it was diagnosed so you can close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that since `RIGHT JOIN` works and gives correct answers (and probably a bogus user id) while a `LEFT JOIN` doesn't give any results related to coupons at all, the coupons are registered on a non existing user.

`LEFT JOIN` demands that data exists in the left part of the table that possibly exists in the right side, while `RIGHT JOIN` does the reverse. In other words, data exists in your rightmost table (coupon) that doesn't have any connection to the left side (user)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to use a `RIGHT JOIN` to get all records form the `Coupon` table.

Comment: i tried it gives me one row in result and i have 2 users ..... i also want result for every user

Comment: and Please note that the resultant row is showing accurate result , now the problem is that i need result for every user

Answer (score 0):

You not using the correct join.
You want to get coupon for a user id?
Use this join.
FROM 
   Users AS us
LEFT JOIN 
   Coupon c ON us.Id = c.Userid
if this does not work then use:
FROM 
   Users AS us
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   Coupon c ON us.Id = c.Userid